# How can I save my google play account? My old email is being closed and I can't find a way to add a new one

Tags: google-play-store

I have attempted to add an alternate email, but it says I don't have permission. This is an old work email that is being closed. I am trying to save my google play account, but can't find a way to transfer it to a new email. Let me reiterate that it says I don't have permission to add an alternate email.

Comment: Log in to gmail in your android device using the account you want to use in play store and turn on sync. This may add the account to the play store.

Comment: @bashBedlam The Link you've attached again points to this post. Kindly correct it